# What is the easiest method to add a half circle cut out

Tags: modeling

Just wondering what is the easiest method to achieve half circle cutouts on the side of a 'cube' OR a link to a suitable video tutorial. See image. The cutouts can be the entire height on the sides (not as per the image) as the object will not be viewed closeup. Just a very simple object.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Add a cylinder, then size and move it to where you want it to be.
Step 2: Add a boolean modifier onto the box, and select the cylinder as the object.
Optional step 3: apply the modifier by selecting the modifier, and pressing Ctrl+a, or pressing apply on the modifier

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a dream and now that I know to add the Boolean Modifier I have learned something else.

Comment: Glad to help :)